# Jupyter Notebook - ModuleNotFoundError when import selfmade module

Tags: jupyter, modulenotfounderror

I can't import any of my selfmade moduls into my jupyter-notebook script.
Pip installed modules like numpy or pandas work.
when calling os.listdir() for my current work directory, the modules are shown.

The current work directory also appears in my sys.path